# How can I add a function inside my .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, unix

I need to use a modified grep function to find certain jobs on our cronjob repositories (cvs & git) in a more automated way.  So I got these functions already made for that job, but not sure how to enter them into my profile so I can use them like any other Unix command.

The usage should be something like: grepcon <text_to_search>

The function is as follows:

```
function grepcron {

   echo 'in cvs'
   cd /somedir/otherdir
   grep -irn $1 country1/crontab.* country2/crontab.*
   cd -

   echo 'in git'
   cd /somedir/crontabs/user1/
   grep -irn $1  
}
```

Is there any way I can add this to my profile? So every time I log into my user, it loads automatically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add your function to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.